# Elastic Search autocompletion/suggestion Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to implement a search as you type functionality in Elastic Search using Java API. The queries that I want to transform to Java are below. 
Do you have any idea, how can I execute this queries in Java?
These queries are very similar but I want to solve at least one.

This is my initial approach:

```
 SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("kal")
            .setTypes("products")
            .setQuery(multiMatchQuery("description_en", "name", "description_en"))// Query
            .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
            .get();
    SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();
    for (SearchHit hit : results) {
        String sourceAsString = hit.getSourceAsString();
        Map<String, SearchHitField> responseFields = hit.getFields();
        SearchHitField field = responseFields.get("product_id");
        Map map = hit.getSource();
        System.out.println(map.toString());
    }
```

Queries:

```
POST /kal/products/_search?pretty
{
    "suggest": {
        "name-suggest" : {
            "prefix" : "wine",
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "suggest_name"
            }
        }
    }
}

GET /kal/products/_search
{ "query": {
    "prefix" : { 
      "name" : "wine",
      "description": "wine"
    }
  }
}

GET /kal/products/_search
{ 
  "query" : {
        "multi_match" : {
            "fields" : ["name", "description_en"],
            "query" : "description_",
            "type" : "phrase_prefix"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Finding the right java sdk methods?

Comment: @MeiSign 
I edited my question! :)